# How to set sender's email send from specific domain only?

Tags: php, html, email

For example, i only want the sender's email is from "anything@abc.com", if other email like "anything@cde.com" is not allow, only @abc.com is allowed. How should i do that?

> let say $_POST['Sender']="anything@abc.com";
>
> ```
> $to = "someone@example.com";
> $subject = "Test mail";
> $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
> $from = $_POST['Sender'];
> $headers = "From:" . $from;
>
> mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
> echo "Mail Sent.";
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just wrap it within an if statement:

```
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = $_POST['Sender'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;

if ($from === "anything@abc.com") {
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `strstr` function to strip the first part of the email off (everything before @) like so:

```
$from = strstr($_POST["Sender"], "@");

if($from == "@abc.com") {
    // send mail
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php for more information on the `strstr` function